# How to make type support for named curry in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript-generics

> Def: **Named curry**.

- **Named part** means the function accepts all its arguments in single object. Kind of like python arguments. This way I can specify args in any permutation by name specification and I force the user of function to know the name.
- This object can be passed chunk by chunk until all props are gathered - **curry part**

```js
/*
 * Goal: Named curry with type support
 *
 */


type FunctorState = {
  a: number;
  b: string;
  c: boolean;
}

/**
 * Here all keys get removed and it's kind of ok since we have no concretization
 * of partial
 */
type Test<T> = Omit<T, keyof Partial<T>>;

type NamedCurry<
  State, 
  Chunk extends Partial<State> = Partial<State>, 
  REST = Omit<State, keyof Chunk>
> = (a: Chunk) => NamedCurry<REST>;


const curryTest: NamedCurry<FunctorState> = a => {
  //disregart the implementation it's runtime anyways...
  const a_construction = a;
  return curryTest;
}

/**
 * Here still all the keys get removed which sucks! Type deduction should insert
 * typeof {a: 5} and then this could work
 */
const curryConcreteStep1 = curryTest({
  a: 5,
});

const curryConcreteStep2 = curryConcreteStep1({
  a: 3
})
```

## Anyone knows hot to solve this?

Comment: This works much better 
type NamedCurry<
  State, 
  Chunk extends Partial<State> = Partial<State>
> = <C extends Chunk>(a: C) => NamedCurry<Omit<State, keyof C>>;

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the interesting problem. I've also included a terminal state (all args exhausted) and to ignore undefined values.

I've come up with this solution:

```
type Arguments = {
    [index: string | number | symbol]: any
}

type FunctorState = {
    a: number;
    b: string;
    c: boolean;
}

type IgnoreUndefined<T extends Partial<Arguments>> = {
    [Key in keyof T as T[Key] extends undefined ? never: Key]: T
}

type Remainder<Full extends Arguments, Args extends Partial<Full>> = Omit<Full, keyof IgnoreUndefined<Args>>

type Curried<Full extends Arguments, R> = <T extends Partial<Full>>(args: T) => (keyof Remainder<Full, T> extends never ? R : Curried<Remainder<Full, T>, R>)

const curriedTest: Curried<FunctorState, string> = (args) => undefined!! // don't care, not about the implementation of this thing

const step1 = curriedTest({a: 2})

const unchanged = step1({b: undefined})

const step2 = unchanged({b: "test", c: true})
```

As an interesting sidenote. It is also possible to extend this to partials inside partials, by throwing another map over the defined and adjusting their values and once their values reduce to the terminal state, throw out their keys.

Comment: Glad you enjoyed the problem just as I did. Still not perfect but very much there. You added some great stuff. IE curriedTest accepts property s: 'asdf' not found in state. Any reference for where to learn typescript meta programming  like this? I use jump to def of these meta functions and then trial and error...

Comment: In my case, I just like going straight to the language documentation. As for how to learn meta programming... just long nights of slamming my head against the problem, reading other meta programming examples. A good place to start is functional programming concepts, and then interpreting a Type just as a pure function. It transfers really well to meta programming.

I read an article on how to write an interpreter purely through types quite a while ago, that helped me to get into it, but I can't recall which one it was specifically.